# Find x^y using While statement

Tags: c++

Please help me to solve this:

Using while statement write a C++ program that prompt the user to input two numbers (x, y) then find x^y.

Sample Run:

Please enter the values of x and y

**7**

**0**

7 ^ 0 = 1

Please enter the values of x and y

**5**

**6**

5 ^ 6 = 15625

P.S no pow statement please.
i did it with power statement (its easy) but i need it without the pow statement
thats what i did

int counter,x,y,ttl;
    counter = 0;

```
while (counter == 0){
    cout << "Please enter the values of x and y ";
    cin >> x >> y;
    ttl = pow(x,y);

    counter++;
}
cout << x << " ^ " << y << " = " << ttl ;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: The simplest (but not the quickest) way to exponentiate is by repeated multiplication. Use a loop to repeat the multiplication. If you have any specific problems doing that, ask specific questions about them.

Comment: Note for the future: some characters that might have some meaning in one context might have a different meaning in another. While the caret (^) is used to mean exponentiation in some contexts, in programming and in particular in C++ it means `xor`. Try to at least on the first use describe the intended meaning of anything but the most obvious operators.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three solutions
*(although the first doesn't use a while-loop)*

```
int power(int x, int y)
{
    return (y==1)
    ?x:x*
    power(x, --y);
}
```

Or, if you really want a while-loop:

```
int power(int x, int y)
{
    while (y-1)
    return x*power(x, --y);
    return x;
}
```

How about using "goes-to":

```
int power(int x, int y)
{
    int r = 1;
    while (y --> 0) r *= x; return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since user3041987 specified that a while statement should be used, maybe we can actually write something that uses a while loop :):

```
int power(int x, int y)
{
  int result = 1;
  int i = 0;
  while(i<y)
  {
    result *= x; 
    ++i;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
int x,y,prod=1;
cout<<"Please enter the values of x and y ";
cin>>x>>y;

while (y>0)
{
 prod*=x;
 y--;
}
cout<<x<<"^"<<y<<"= "<<prod;
```

Comment: i did it using POW #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int counter,x,y,ttl;
 counter = 0;

 while (counter == 0){
  cout << "Please enter the values of x and y ";
  cin >> x >> y;
  ttl = pow(x,y);

  counter++;
 }
 cout << x << " ^ " << y << " = " << ttl ;
 return 0;

Comment: but teacher said don't use pow :(

Comment: @user3041987: Did teacher say "please let stack overflow crowd solve it for you?"